# Vlookup a value from col2 that is stored in col1 in the same table

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4],
                  'col1':['a','b','c','d'],
                  'col2':['b','a','d','c']})
df
```

```
    id  col1    col2
0    1   a        b
1    2   b        a
2    3   c        d
3    4   d        c
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
    id  col1    col2    col2_id
0    1   a        b        2
1    2   b        a        1
2    3   c        d        4
3    4   d        c        3
```

I tried using `pd.merge` but I know there is a more efficient way to do this with bigger samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using index trickery (disclaimer: did not do any timing, so you'll have to determine what works best/fastest yourself)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4],
                  'col1':['a','b','c','d'],
                  'col2':['b','a','d','c']})

df["col2_id"] = df["id"].set_axis(df["col1"]).reindex(df["col2"]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

```
   id col1 col2  col2_id
0   1    a    b        2
1   2    b    a        1
2   3    c    d        4
3   4    d    c        3
```

Comment: This absolutely awesome thank you

Comment: This is much faster than the merge one

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is shorter way to do this. In the meantime you could try:

```
(df.iloc[:, [0, 1]].merge(df.iloc[:, [0, 2]], left_on='col1', right_on='col2', suffixes=('', '_x'))
 .rename(columns = {'id_x' :'col2_id'}))

   id col1  col2_id col2
0   1    a        2    a
1   2    b        1    b
2   3    c        4    c
3   4    d        3    d
```

Comment: This is exactly how I did it, I was just looking for a more efficient way to do it.
But thank you very much for your time